# If $(-3,a,1)$ is perpendicular to $(1,0,-3)$ then find $a$

Tags: vectors

I had a math test today and I got this question. The points represent vectors and for vectors to be perpendicular, the dot product must be zero, but in the given question no matter what the value of $a$ is, I get $-6$ as dot product. Is the question wrong or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You're not. Probably there's a typo.

Comment: Means the question is wrong??

Comment: Yes – unless there's an error in your transcription.

Comment: Could it probably be *another* dot product and not the standard one?

Comment: DonAntonio nope the to be perpendicular the standard dot product should be zero i guess

Comment: The exact question only uses lambda instead of a

Comment: **Hint**: $\text{For two vectors } \vec{u}, \vec{v} \neq \vec{0}, \space \space \space \vec{u} \bot \vec{v} \iff \vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=0$. In your example, dot product is $-6$ (as you already wrote in the Q), so A may be $a \in \emptyset$.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak What does that mean? As it is igiven, it is clear $\;a\;$ is a number from some numbers system ( most probably, $\;\Bbb R\,,\,\,\Bbb C\;$) . Besides this, the empty set has no element at all...

Comment: To @DonAntonio: in other words there is no $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that vectors $(-3,a, 1)$ and $(1, 0, -3)$ are perpendicular. Maybe Q is wrong in some part...

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak That's the standard way to write it, not something rather weird looking as $\;a\in\emtpyspace\;$ ...even if there's agreement on that.